# Disk Rename in LVM

Tags: lvm, ubuntu-14.04, diskmanagement

I installed ubuntu 14.04 with LVM, the disk name was showing properly as I had specified while installation till I performed apt-get updated && upgrade.

Before Upgrade

```
/dev/mapper/UBUNTU--VG01-UBUNTU--ROOT  37G  1.3G   34G   4% /
/dev/mapper/UBUNTU--VG01-UBUNTU--MNT   93G   60M   88G   1% /MNT
```

After Upgrade

```
/dev/dm-0  37G  1.3G   34G   4% /
```

but `/mnt` partition name remains as it is.

```
/dev/mapper/UBUNTU--VG01-UBUNTU--MNT   93G   60M   88G   1% /MNT
```

Now I need the name which I had specified while installation. How do I rename it.

Please help.

Comment: Please run lvdisplay command https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LV_display.html and post it here. I will try to give you the exact command to rename the volume.

Comment: `LV Path                /dev/UBUNTU-VG01/UBUNTU-ROOT`
`LV Name                UBUNTU-ROOT`
`VG Name                UBUNTU-VG01`
`LV UUID                0bs9dH-456s-pZuv-FIBg-rrP5-L4i2-mSEhsa`
`LV Write Access        read/write`
`LV Creation host, time ServerHost736, 2016-10-19 10:26:47 +0530`
`LV Status              available`
`# open                 1`
`LV Size                37.25 GiB`
`Current LE             9536`
`Segments               1`
`Allocation             inherit`
`Read ahead sectors     auto`
`- currently set to     256`
`Block device           252:0`